# Reading XML from VB.Net and storing in variable

Tags: xml, vb.net

Hello I am trying to retrieve a 'tag'(Is it called that?) from an XML webpage. Once I make a post request from my vb.net app it sends a command to my online webserver and redirects me to a page that has entries that change each time. The page that im redirected to that changes each time looks something like this:

```
<mainpage> <id>hello</id> <random>176</random> </mainpage>
```

What vb.net code would I use to retrieve the id (In this case 'hello') and store it in a variable. I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in vb.net (not tested)

```
dim doc as XDocument = XDocument.Parse(stringContainingXML)
dim valueOfIdElement as string = (doc...<id>).first.value
```

You should look at the documentation for the [System.Xml.Linq namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx).

Comment: I am a newb and I don't understand what you mean by 'doc...<id>'